# accessing Raphael attribute

Tags: jquery, raphael

I'm trying to set then get an attribute from a Raphael rectangle, but I'm getting "undefined". I've tried a number of variations, but nothing is working. Can someone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

```
var $belo_victoria = paper.rect(383.281, 557.583, 59.001, 82.303);
    $belo_victoria.attr({ "fill": "#722364", 
                           "transform": "T97,123r35",
                          "pid": "28B23"                               });
console.log($belo_victoria.pid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that Raphael attributes will be available directly as properties on a given Raphael-managed element -- best practices would suggest using the `Element`.[data](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data) method instead.  Like this:

```
var $belo_victoria = paper.rect(383.281, 557.583, 59.001, 82.303);
$belo_victoria.attr({ "fill": "#722364", 
                       "transform": "T97,123r35" } );
$belo_victoria.data( "pid", "28B23");

console.log($belo_victoria.data( "pid" ));
```